# Test firefox for virus/hijacker

Tags: firefox, browser, malware

I am a bit concerned about my firefox being hijacked or something. I went to a website and it opened a pop-up asking firefox to be updated.

I knew immediately it was a malicious code because it wouldn't let me close it. I had to kill firefox through terminal. Next time I opened firefox the pop-up reappeared.
So I just restarted the computer and everything seemed alright.

I may be overthinking but since I utilise this computer for online banking operations it's better to be wary.

So what do you suggest me to do to be sure about firefox integrity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had to kill firefox through terminal. Next time I opened firefox the pop-up reappeared.

FF by default restores your previous session automatically if it detects a crash, hence reloaded the pop-up. (This behavior stops after multiple consecutive crashes.)

> So what do you suggest me to do to be sure about firefox integrity

It is unlikely your system is infected, though you can [create](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles#w_creating-a-profile) a new browser profile or [refresh](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings) your current one if you are worried your browser has been hijacked.